# in bash what is the best way to copy a file, and if it is a symlink also copy the linked-to file?

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

So I know that I can use `if [[ -L "/home/user/link" ]] ; then ...` to check if my file is a symlink and then followed by something like `cp $(realpath "/home/user/link") /home/new/location`. But I am wandering if there is a trick to do this automatically with say, `cp` or `rsync` such that it always copies the link AND the linked-to files? - or is writing this manually the only way - if so, that's ok, I can just write my own function. I have not found anything, but I have a suspicion there might be some clever trick out there to do this -might be wrong :o

Actually here is my usecase example:

```
libtest.so
libtestd.so -> libtest.so
libtest.so.1 -> libtest.so
libtestd.so.1 -> libtest.so.1
```

Where `d` suffix is debug. In this case the debug and release are the same file, so when I do a release build I get the correct real file. When I do a debug build I only get the symlink, but I also want to get the linked-to file.

I don't really want to always use rsync's follow the link because there are other exceptions to this rule where I end up getting duplicates like the so.1 files... So if I wanted to copy the debug files I would want to end up with all the files, but if I copy for release then I just end up with `libtest.so` and `libtest.so.1` (link).

E.g. given the files above, if I want the file `libtestd.so` - then my function would take `libtestd.so` and produce itself (as a link) and the linked to file.

So:

`cpy_func /dir_source/libtest.so /dir_dest`

Would take the symlink `libtestd.so` from:

```
/dir_source/libtest.so
/dir_source/libtestd.so -> libtest.so
/dir_source/libtest.so.1 -> libtest.so
/dir_source/libtestd.so.1 -> libtest.so.1
```

And copy it to the dest folder like this:

```
/dir_dest/libtest.so
/dir_dest/libtestd.so -> libtest.so
```

i.e. it copies the symlink AND the file that is pointed to by the symlink

Comment: --preserve=links should do this?

Comment: Include a [mre], it's unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: @RamanSailopal no, I was doing this previously, but this just means the symlink turns into a non-symlink, copy of the linked-to file with the name of the symlink file... I'll add a more precise example of what I want...

Comment: @oguzismail I know about minimal examples, but in this case I can't really write one, because my example is just files in a directory. My question more along the lines of are there some tricks to help me do this - similar to `--preserve=links`, but not that exact feature. I am asking if there is a feature that copies the link AND the file linked to - there may not be (I can't find one)

Answer (score 0):

I do not pretend what follows is the simplest or most elegant, but it works in my tests.

My tests setup

```
a/source
a/link1 -> source
a/link2 -> source
b/
c/
```

Directories `b` and `c` have no files in them.
The code below allows you to do these:

- ./cpy_func a/source b
  Result:

  ```
  a/source
  a/link1 -> source
  a/link2 -> source

  b/source
  b/link1 -> source
  b/link2 -> source

  c/
  ```

  Since the first argument is a file, it copies the file and all softlinks that point to that file into the target directory `b`.
- ./cpy_func a/link2 c
  Result:

  ```
  a/source
  a/link1 -> source
  a/link2 -> source

  b/source
  b/link1 -> source
  b/link2 -> source

  c/source
  c/link2 -> source
  ```

  Sine the first argument is a softlink, it copies the link and the file it points to into the target directory `c`.

The code for `cpy_func`:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
###############################################################################

# Verify arguments
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]
then
    echo "Usage: cpy_func <SRC> <DEST.DIR>"
    echo "       SRC: source file or source soft link"
    exit 1
else
    src="$1"
    src_file=$(basename "$src")
    src_dir=$(dirname "$src")
    dest_dir="$2"
fi

# Verify destination directory
if [[ ! -d "$dest_dir" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: Directory $dest_dir does not exist."
    exit 2
fi

# Verify source existence (not type specific for now)
if [[ ! -e "$src" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: $src does not exist."
    exit 3
fi

# Process a softlink
if [[ -L "$src" ]]
then
    echo "INFO: copying soft link $src and the target file..."
    # copy the file
    cp -v "$(readlink -f "$src")" "$dest_dir"
    # copy the link
    cp -vd "$src" "$dest_dir"
    exit 0
fi

# Process a file
if [[ -f "$src" ]]
then
    echo "INFO: copying file $src and its soft links..."
    # copy the file itself
    cp -v "$src" "$dest_dir"
    # copy softlinks
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' link
    do
        src_link=$(basename "$link")
        # Recreate the link in the destination directory
        ln -vs "$src_file" "$dest_dir/$src_link"
    done < <(find "$src_dir" -lname "$src_file" -print0)
    exit 0
fi

# If we got here, then $src is neither a softlink nor a file, exit!
echo "INFO: $src is neither a softlink, nor a file.  Nothing to do."
exit 0
```

As you will see, the first argument is processed differently based on it's type (file or softlink).  I did this since in your question you sometimes use the file, sometimes the softlink, so I decided to cover both cases.

This code does not handle links to links to files.  Only links to files.  Making it recursive is left to the reader to experiment :-)